# Yii2 multilanguage URLs

Tags: php, internationalization, yii2, multilingual, yii-url-manager

is it possible to create a multilanguage site in Yii2, and also have the URLs translated? Example:

```
mysite.com/anmeldung
mysite.com/en/login
```

Both URLs should point to the same controller/action (e.g. site/login ), but the language should be respected - so the first one is the default language, the second one is en = english

Also when creating a URL `Url::to('site/login')` should create the correct translated URL according to the current language.

I think this is a standard issue, however, I was not able to find a solution or plugin for that. All the plugins I found were just adding the language param in fron onf the url slug, but using the same url slug for all lanuages.

Any help and ideas appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `UrlRule`, by creating a class that implements `\yii\web\UrlRuleInterface`.

When parsing the requests, retrieve the language and return it as parameter together with the new route. Later, save the language configuration in controller's action.

When creating the url, construct the url by using current stored language.

The implementation will be application specific and depends on users to implement it.

Comment: In theory it seems easy. Any examples? I wanted to use [yii2-localeurls](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls) for managing the language param, but the question is, where to save the URL slugs? How to easy intergrat them in the URL config?

Comment: I've never used yii2-localeurls, but I guess they uses default yii2 localization module. Have you tried to save the translation in the localization configuration?

Comment: the problem is to "translate" the URL slugs. It does not use that, though it may not be a bad idea.